# Add photos in custom album also added in default Album "Camera Roll"

Tags: iphone, ios5

In my application I am creating a new photo album "My Album" and user can export photos in that newly created album. But it is showing at both albums in "My Album" and in default album "Camera Roll"

So can any one tell me that is this default behavior OR is can be issue in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: this is default behavior into iPhone

Comment: @OKNC2 i have the same issue. have you resolved it ?

Comment: @Coder no, not resolved. It's default behavior as neon has commented above.

Comment: @NimitParekh photo is  saved only custom album no camera roll is possible ?