# Adding photo to custom folder using PHPhotoLibrary also adds photo to camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, camera-roll, phphotolibrary

I am using PHPhotoLibrary to create a custom folder and add pictures in it. It works ok, but the picture I am adding to the custom folder is also added to the "camera roll" folder. I found this old thread [Add photos in custom album also added in default Album "Camera Roll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142289/add-photos-in-custom-album-also-added-in-default-album-camera-roll), where somebody says that it is the normal behaviour, but since the comment is from 3 years ago, I would like to know if in the latests iOS versions there is a way to add the picture only to the custom folder. I have searched for some documentation to confirm this, but no luck.

The code I am using:

```
class TMPhotoAlbum {

  static let albumName = "Custom Album"
  static let sharedInstance = TMPhotoAlbum()

  var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

  init() {

    func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection! {

      let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
      fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", TMPhotoAlbum.albumName)
      let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

      if (collection.firstObject != nil) {
        return collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
      }

      return nil
    }

    if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
      self.assetCollection = assetCollection
      return
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
      PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(TMPhotoAlbum.albumName)
      }) { success, _ in
        if success {
          self.assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
        }
    }
  }

  func saveImage(image: UIImage, completion: (Bool, NSError?) -> Void) {

    if assetCollection == nil {
      return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
      let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
      let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
      let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)
      albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder!])
      }, completionHandler: completion )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still normal and expected behaviour: Photos/Videos in user created albums are only references to the original in the "Camera Roll". This concept is existent since iOS 5 and hasn't changed so far.

The only photos/videos being not part of the Camera Roll are photos/videos synced by iTunes, Shared Photostreams and items imported with the Camera Connection Kit.